# Code to calculate the unicode character for a fraction in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

I'm looking for a way in C# .NET to get the Unicode character corresponding to a given fraction. In my code I have the numerator and denominator and I need to work out how to get the corresponding Unicode character from these, which is then displayed in a WinForms combobox.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post an example of what you are looking for? What unicode character for what value?

Comment: What numerators/denominators are you expecting to use? Unicode can only display a few of those numbers, so if you will use others you may want a different solution.

Comment: Example:
Numerator = 3, Denominator 8 (i.e. 3/8)
Unicode Character 'VULGAR FRACTION THREE EIGHTHS' (U+215C)

murgatroid99, I doubt I'll need fractions beyond sixteenths which are supported.

Answer (score 4):

You will need a lookup table, there is no algorithmic method available (Unicode codepoints are not allocated like that).

Of course most fractions do not have a codepoint, only a few "common" fractions have been added.

And of course, even with the codepoint your typeface may not include them.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string VulgarFraction(int numerator, int denominator)
{
  if(denominator == 0)
    return "\u221E";
  if(denominator < 0)
    return VulgarFraction(-numerator, -denominator);
  return numerator.ToString() + '\u2044' + denominator.ToString();
}
```

The precomposed vulgar fractions are included for compatibility, and not encouraged. Use U+2044 FRACTION SLASH to indicate a fraction. This indicates the desire to render as a fraction to a layout system, and is also widely supported by less sophisticated rendering methods.

If you really do need to use the precomposed characters, then a look-up table is the only reasonable way (you could build a big set of branching ifs and elses, but it's more work for less performance).